# Why do we fall when we ride bicycle slowly but we don't when riding it fastly

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, stability

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why doesn't the bike fall if going with a high speed?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/506/why-doesnt-the-bike-fall-if-going-with-a-high-speed)

Why is it that, when we ride bicycle at good speed, it is perfectly balanced and we don't fall. But we lose balance when we ride bicycle at lower speeds.

Comment: Because the movement of the handlebars will make the moving bicycle tilt, and you can compensate for falling. But on a stationary bicycle, moving the handlebars doesn't do anything. This is answered many places.

Comment: @Ron Maimon: Sorry, I didn't get you.

Comment: Because when you are going forward, if you turn the handlebars to the right, you tilt to the right. If you turn the handlebars to the left, you tilt to the left. You can compensate for falling by tilting the handlebars. On a stationary bicycle, turning the handlebars doesn't help prevent falls. This is answered many places.

Comment: @claws: Instead of falling left, you turn the handlebar left, you go left and thus you prevent you from falling left. A still bicycle does not turn left or right.

Comment: Isn't this due to the spinning of the wheel acting like a gyroscope and resisting turning/falling over?