# How do bikes stay upright?

Tags: gyroscopes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why doesn't the bike fall if going with a high speed?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/506/why-doesnt-the-bike-fall-if-going-with-a-high-speed)

How does a bike stay upright? I know there are various theories involving castor effects, and gyroscopic motion but as far as I'm aware no one knows for certain how a bike stays up right.

What is the best theory right now?

Comment: see [here](http://arstechnica.com/science/news/2011/04/moving-bikes-stay-uprightbut-not-for-the-reasons-we-thought.ars) for answer

Comment: The paper here clearly answers most of your questions. The title is apt which states > A Bicycle Can Be Self-Stable Without Gyroscopic or Caster Effects http://www.sciencemag.org/content/332/6027/339.abstract