# Why a two wheeler is not pulled down by gravity while moving

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

As for every two wheeler the centre of mass  will be much closer to earth in leaning position than in standing. but while moving it doesn't fall (lean).what kind of forces are preventing the falling of 2wheeler.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't a bike/bicycle fall if going with a high speed?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/506/)

Comment: See also http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/132449/

Answer (score 0):

leaning happens when you are taking a turn (or making a revolution or a part of it). Centrifugal force caused in this revolution prevents the two wheeler from falling.

Comment: Hi Gautham, you really need to spell this idea out in a lot more detail.