# Effect of forces (gravitational or other) on a wheel out cycle

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, velocity

It is not a question. It is my own doubt.

> Suppose a wheel is moving towards the North. The Wheel shouldn't fall if the wheel had not stopped is moving. But if the wheel stops it's moving them it will falls either the easy or West (I know in one case it didn't fall and stand still, So Just think about bicycles. In this case the cycle may not fall too but the chance is very low). So give me a idea why the wheel is falling (in some cases) and not falling (in some cases). Please give me a good idea.

**Note:** If I assume the wheel as a ring then it is given that the width is so small like a coin.If I stand the coin then it will surely fall but if I forced it and moved out then it won't fall till it stops. My question is why??

**Caution:** It is not duplicate of the question which was asked before.See the previous question tells us that why bicycles falls while running at a high speed.But my question is why cycles didn't fall while driving but falls when it has no motion?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/506/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/132449/why-do-we-fall-down-when-the-bicycle-slows-down

Comment: @sammy gerbil & John Rennie I explained why my question is different to the previous .So why you mark it as duplicate??Please reopen it

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain in a way that will help, without arithmetic. let us look at the wheel because it is more simple than the bike. we will give the wheel the shape of a flat hoop or ring with a certain width "W", and say that it is standing up, pointing north as you say, and not moving.

If we push the wheel slowly and gently at the top in the east direction by a small amount which is less than W and then release it, it will tip back in the west direction and perhaps rock back and forth west-east-west-east for a while but it will not tip over and fall.

But if we push the wheel slowly and gently a distance east which is bigger than W, then the wheel will not tip back to the west but it will instead continue tipping to the east and fall down.

If W is large, like an automobile tire, then you can tip it over a larger distance and it will not fall over. if w is small, it will take only a tiny disturbance- like a tiny rock under the wheel- to cause it to fall over.

And if the shape of the wheel is not flat but is instead round like a bicycle tire, then it will be impossible to get it to stand upright by itself. as soon as you let go of it, it will immediately fall over.

Comment: The question is updated .Please check the last paragraph.

Comment: because this question has been marked as a duplicate from another user, I recommend you look at the answers posted earlier to it.