# Can a bicycle whose front wheel cannot turn left/right stay upright?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics, stability

Most [sensible explanations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/132548/218392) of why a bicycle stays upright involve the turning left/right of the front wheel.

If a bicycle's front wheel cannot turn left/right, can it stay upright while being pedalled? Would it fall over just as quickly as when the bicycle is not moving?