# Why would I feel more balanced when I ride my bike fast?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, rotational-dynamics

When I am a kid I would somehow feel more balanced when I ride my bike fast and feel less balanced when I ride my bike slow (when I am still learning how to ride). Is it a personal thing or there is some scientific reason behind it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't a bike/bicycle fall if going with a high speed?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/506/)