# What keeps a bike from falling while in motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, everyday-life

Okay, so it might seem like a trivial question, but when I suddenly stop my bike (not really fast), I lose balance. Why is that? What keeps me from falling while riding it?

EDIT : The answers in the other question either use terms I don't understand, or don't explain it in a simple and satisfactory way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't a bike/bicycle fall if going with a high speed?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/506/)

Comment: @JohnRennie : None of the answers there give a complete and satisfactory answer.

Comment: I suggest, vs_292, that you then reformulate your question, explaining what you already understand, and which points are unclear, and why.

Comment: Or you could place a bounty on the duplicate question specifying that you want a simpler answer.

Comment: You shouldn’t move at all to hold balance. But your wheels have to be free to hold balance only: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_rollers