# What can I investigate concerning the stability of bikes?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, experimental-physics, stability

I'm in high school, and I'm doing an Extended Essay for IB? I only have 1 bicycle and no fancy tools or measurement equipment, so it has be a pretty simple experiment, but complex enough that I can write 4000 words (lol, so many words xD) on it. What variables can I consider vs. stability of a bike?

P.S. I have a standard mountain bike (don't know the specific specs/model tbh)

This research essay/project is due in 10 days, and I'm pretty desperate lol.

Comment: Just found that, looks great have a look at it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Y4mbT3ozcA it should give you some ideas

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/506/2451 and links therein.