# When we ride a bicycle then we can balance it but when we apply brakes then we need to put our legs down else we may fall, why?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, everyday-life, centrifugal-force

I got this idea while sitting and studying physics in school but not getting answer please try to answer it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't a bike/bicycle fall if going with a high speed?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/506/)

Comment: Try reading this https://theconversation.com/the-mysterious-biomechanics-of-riding-and-balancing-a-bicycle-55093 . A gross explanation :  a bicycle that is not moving will fall (and any weight it carries).. You start with a leg on the ground.. Once in motion angular momentum conservation keeps it going as long as power is supplied for the frictions on the road.

Answer (score 0):

your ability to remain upright on a bike relies on forward motion, and steering. when your forward motion has nearly stopped, so ends your ability to remain upright and you have to put down your landing gear so you don't tip over.

Comment: It's more than forward motion. It would be hard to stay upright on a bike sliding on ice

Comment: did not consider that scenario.

Comment: @AaronStevens because you can't steer it.

Comment: @Aetol Are you adding to what I am saying, or saying my scenario isn't relevant?

Comment: Thank you for giving answer as it will help me in learning physics easily