# Why does a cyclist/motorcyclist bend when making a turn?

Tags: friction, centripetal-force

I've seen this very prominently in the Olympics

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by *bend*? I'm assuming you don't just mean that the bike leans over. Do you means the cyclist moves their body relative to the bike? Can you link to a picture illustrating your question? (I'm not sure you can insert pictures at your current rep, but if provide a link we can edit the picture in for you)

Comment: Concerning leaning: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24/2451

Comment: I can't speak for the OP, but I noticed that in the Tour de France riders always rotate the hip and stick out the knee that points toward the center of the radius of the curve.