# When we ride a bicycle, why do we tend to move left when we turn it right?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics

When we ride a bicycle, we tend to move our body left if we are taking a right turn and vice versa.  Why is it like that?

Comment: Answered almost entirely [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countersteering#Need_to_lean_to_turn).

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24/2451

Answer (score 0):

If the person is moving in a straight line and then takes a right turn then the answer simply is because of inertia. The person initially moving in a st line would continue to move in that direcn and hence when he takes a right turn it would appear that he turns left but actually he is simply trying to maintain his earlier motion..

If he is moving,in a circular track then the answer lies in rotational mechanics. To counter the torque produced by friction thr person would bend atan angle with the verticle , so that the torques by mg and N could balance the torque by friction or else thr cycle would be upside down