# Why can't you ride a bike with a fixed handlebar?

Tags: classical-mechanics, everyday-life

I tried one time, as part of an experiment, to ride a bike with a fixed handle bar. Impossible. So, in any case, our movements made with the handlebar helps us in not falling down. I can feel kinda how, but cannot really put a finger on it. Does anybody know the answer?

Comment: How does your personal inability to perform this act constitute a proof that it's impossible?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Why doesn't a bike/bicycle fall if going with a high speed?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/506/)

Comment: Is it really impossible at a high speed? Getting started could be tricky, but at speed you can ride hands free. I wonder whether you still need to allow the handle bar to turn

Comment: @innifree: Every circus probably has half a dozen people who can take a nap on a unicycle... I think the OP needs to take a closer look at what people can do who are actually not giving up after five minutes.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't ride it because it's very thin and so is bound to fall over to one side or the other.

A more difficult question is why you can ride a bike in normal circumstances. That has already been discussed on this site but as you would expect the answer is related to the steering mechanism.