# Turning a bike, why does it lean?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, centripetal-force, centrifugal-force

I realize this seems like a pretty simple issue of drawing a free body diagram, but I just can't seem to figure it out.

If a bike leans, then it must have had a torque that made it lean. I considered the centripetal force, in this case friction, as a possible source for this torque, but that would create torque in the opposite direction. The only remaining torque causing force in my FBD is weight. But weight was there before the leaning, and would only cause a torque after leaning.

If anything, because of centripetal acceleration, observing from an inertial frame of reference, the bike should lean in the opposite direction because of the introduction of the centripetal force. So the question is, what force causes the bike to start leaning?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Do you ever ride hands off? You lean to make the bike turn, not the other way around.

Comment: @ThePhoton It actually can affect the other in both ways. You use the handlebars to create the lean. If you ride no hands, you actually give a little "jiggle", which because of the angle of the handle-bar stem, causes counter steering to occur by virtue of moving the bike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things that need to be considered. Often it is not the cyclists weight that causes the lean in. Subconsciously, as people learn to ride a bike, they do something called counter-steering.

So for example coming in to turn right, a cyclist will quickly turn the handlebars left to lean the bike to the right due to centripetal acceleration. Once the lean has been achieved, the handlebars are then turned to the right to turn and balance the bike in a turn. Then to upright the bike, the handlebars are turned slightly harder in until it levels (due to increasing the centripetal force outwards relative to the lean), then the bike is straightened, and the handlebars follow.

People don't believe that they do this, it's quite funny.

Comment: I see, but how would this account for the case of a speeding car? If a car turns a bend too quickly, I imagine it will also lean, and in fact often it will over turn. Does the driver unconsciously veer to the opposite side before making a turn?

Comment: @ClovisNyu do a web search on counter steering. Cars don't need to lean, because of their side by side wheel base, to counteract torque from centripetal acceleration around a corner.

Comment: Yea, did a search, drew out a FBD, I'm pretty sure they lean given that the turn is fast enough. There's something called the "Moose Crash Test" where the driver makes a suddenly turn to test whether the car will overturn. Maybe I'm confusing something here...

Comment: @ClovisNyu Do you understand countersteering? That is what causes the lean largely.

Comment: Hmm, so the car won't lean if there is no counter-steering? I think I'm starting to see it. If the driver doesn't counter-steer and just makes a sudden turn, he will just skid. But this raises more questions as I'm currently working on a problem that claims that past a certain angular velocity, the outer wheels will lift off the ground and the car will roll.

Comment: @ClovisNyu Hopefully this can be taken to chat soon. I feel there is a disconnect in what we are discussing. Firstly, car's don't need to lean. They may lean out due to centripetal force though. Please explain why cars are relevant.

Your second point, yes. Car's will roll with enough force. You'd calculate the moments about the outer edge of the car, and when the centripetally applied moment exceeds the weight moment, it will flip. This has nothing to do with a bike.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. So am I correct in saying that leaning and rolling are 2 different phenomena? The reason why I had ask about a bike to begin with is that the first part of the question had asked us about the rotational equilibrium that the bike was in while it was leaning. The second ask for a quantitative explanation as to why a car rolls when it has too much angular velocity. I had assumed that they were about the same physical phenomena.

Comment: Yes, same phenomena, but obviously they lean in different directions whilst turning the same way yeah? So what I'm saying the mechanism of creating a lean is different to a car rolling, despite both coming from centripetal force.

Comment: Wait, so a car rolls away from the centre of its rotation? Now that you mention it, it sounds like it makes sense. Doesn't feel very intuitive though. Either way, this clears up quite a bit. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @ClovisNyu Well, countersteering is counterintuitive. I completely agree. It logically clicked as I was doing 70mph on a freeway (on a motorbike). It scared the devil out of me. A car rolling outwards I'd imagine is exactly as you'd expect. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The bike would lean in the other direction, due to centripetal force, without a cyclist. A cyclist leans the bike on purpose into the turn, to counteract said centripetal force.

The torque involved is the cyclist's weight as they lean into the turn.