# Angle of banking for bicycle

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram, centripetal-force

According to this [website](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/suny-osuniversityphysics/chapter/6-3-centripetal-force/#:%7E:text=Show%20Solution-,Part%20of%20riding%20a%20bicycle%20involves%20leaning%20at%20the%20correct,.,-%CE%B8%3Dtan%E2%88%921), the angle of banking for a **bicycle** is related to the radius of curvature as:

$$θ = \tan ^{-1} \left(\dfrac{v^2}{rg}\right)$$

[image: enter link description here]

I know how to derive the same for a car on a banked road inclined at θ moving at optimal velocity:

[image]

$$\dfrac{mv^2}r = N \sin θ + μN \cos θ$$

Since $N \cos θ = mg$ and $f = 0$,

$$\dfrac{v^2}r = g \tan θ$$

To my knowledge, the normal always acts perpendicular. So how to derive it for the bicycle?

Comment: Why do you think it is different for a bicycle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose a cyclist is going at a speed u on a circular horizontal road of radius r which is not banked Consider the cycle and the rider together as the system. The centre of mass C of the system is going in a circle with the centre at 0 and radius r[image]

Let us choose O as the origin, OC as the X-axis and vertically upward as the Z-axis. This frame is rotating at an angular speed $\omega = \frac{v}{r}$ about the Z-axis. In this frame the system is at rest. Since we are working from a rotating frame of reference, we will have to apply a centrifugal force on each particle. The net centrifugal force on the system will be $M\omega^2r = \frac{Mv^2}{r}$, where M is the total mass of the system. This force will act through the centre of mass. Since the system is at rest in this frame, no other pseude force is needed.

The cycle is bent at an angle 0 with the vertical.
The forces are
(1) weight Mg.
(ii) normal force $\mathscr{N}$
(iii) friction f and,
(iv) centrifugal force $\frac{Mv^2}{r}$.
In the frame considered, the system is at rest. Thus, the total external force and the total external torque must be zero. Let us consider the torques of all the forces about the point A. The torques of N and f about A are zero because these forces pass through A

The torque of Mg about A is Mg(AD) in the clockwise direction and that of $\frac{Mv^2}{r}$ is $\frac{Mv^2}{r}(CD)$ in the anti clockwise direction. For rotational equilibrium, $$Mg(AD) = \frac{Mv^2}{r}(CD)$$ or, $$\frac{AD}{CD} = \frac{v^2}{rg}$$ or$$\tan{\theta} = \frac{v^2}{rg}$$

Thus the cyclist bends at an angle $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{v^2}{rg}\right)$ with the vertical.
Hope it helps.